# A problem regarding determiners as the object

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adjectives, nouns, determiners

In an editorial I found a sentence.

> It notes that East and South Asia have the highest number of deaths due to air pollution; by one estimate, it killed about **1.24 million** in India in 2017.

Here 1.24 million is just a number. By extension can it be also used to mean 1.24 million people. Are these types of constructions correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes: "almost 1.24 million" is a determiner, but the noun (probably "people") that it determines has been ellipted for some reason. I would include it.

Answer (score 1):

The noun that 1.24 million is determining has been omitted. This is an example of ellipsis: words can be omitted when they can be understood from the context. The context here suggests that air pollution killed 1.24 million *people*.  This kind of ellipsis is quite common.